# Are there any techniques to arrange or list ideas from a short text?

Tags: technique

For example I wrote this:

> !Paying! for exams, and also books
>   to pass them is only a **small price** /
>   to give *poor people* the opportunity /
>   ...to contribute for the MANSIONS of the people in charge of the edu|ca|tio|nal system

There are some ideas there but since it is irony I'm getting a bit confused by my own writing (I'm a heavy drinker). Is there any technique to underline and list the ideas in this short text?

**EDIT:**

This paragraph have a meessage for the reader, I want to find a way of arranging those ideas or group them.

Comment: Bullets and the "underline" function usually work for me. :) You're being vague, dear. Sober up and rewrite the question so it's a little clearer, please?

Comment: @Lauren Ipsum that was a good one :). Please see my  EDIT.

Comment: Still looks like bullets to me.

Comment: Vote to close as not a real question.

Comment: Would the answer be "yes", there are?